# Unable to add UIScrollView to UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationbar, titleview

I want my `scrollview` to be added as `UINavigationBar's titleview`, but strangely I am unable to do so.

**In viewDidLoad:**

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 20 - 45 - 2);
    CGRect frame = navController.view.frame;
    frame.size.height -= 20;
    [self.view addSubview:navController.view];

    UIScrollView *someview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    someview.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    navController.navigationItem.titleView = someview;
```

It is a very simple piece of code, but I can't figure out that what I am missing. Please someone help me... Thanks.

**Side Note:** I am initiating `UINavigationController` without any root controller, since my first concern is adding scrollview to navigationbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`navController.navigationItem` is never actually added to the navigation bar. It exists because the nav controller is a subclass of `UIViewController`. But it isn't used.

Add a root view controller to the nav controller and add the scroll view as its `navigationItem` `titleView`.

Depending on what you're after you may also want to subclass the nav controller to inject your custom `titleView` when any new view controller is pushed.

Comment: Ok I am getting your idea. Can you tell me how can I push my custom titleview in custom navigationcontroller?

Comment: Start by adding your controller as the nav controller delegate and implementing `navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:`.

Comment: Instead of `navigationItem` you could use the `topItem` property right?

Comment: @RyanPoolos, not sure if it is `nil` to begin with, but if set it should work, yes.

Comment: Just double checking. Your answer is definitely more portable and fullproof.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the scroll view to a container view. Something like this:

```
navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 20 - 45 - 2);
CGRect frame = navController.view.frame;
frame.size.height -= 20;
[self.view addSubview:navController.view];

UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(...)];
UIScrollView *someview = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
someview.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
[container addSubview:someview];
navController.navigationItem.titleView = container;
```